# what is the best way to export an animated graph from excel to power point

Tags: excel, graph, point, animated

I have created a series of graphs with excel, that all present the evolution in time of some quantities.So, behind this I have added the macro that defines the evolution of these numbers at its each specific time.

Now, I would like to present these charts on power point as well.

What is the best way to go about it?

Save all these charts as images and then create a gif ?

I would like to know the options so I don't invest too much time in one method that maybe is not the simplest.